# How to write a module that changes user role when account is created

Tags: 7, users

I am writing a module called "Applicant" and I want it to add a role called "applicant" to a user after the user creates their own account.

**applicant.info**

```
name = Applicant
description = Handles Applicant User Actions
core = 7.x
```

**applicant.module**

```
<?php
function applicant_user_insert(){

}
```

What would I include inside of the hook in applicant.module to access the current user's roles and add "Applicant"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [api page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7) for reference. Replace the values for your "Applicant" role:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_user_insert().
 */
function applicant_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  // id of role (probably not neccessary, added here to avoid multiple assertions)
  $key = 3;
  // role's machine name
  $role = 'administrator';
  $account->roles[$key] = $role;
}
```

Comment: why is $key set to 3? Can we access the current key of the user without setting it statically?

Comment: $key is not the user id, it is the role id. see `{role}` table in your database for reference

Comment: you probably could do $account->roles[] = 'newrole'; as well, but that could cause ->roles to contain multiple times 'newrole' and I am not sure how drupal would react to that, so either add the id, or use in_array().

Comment: +1 for working code but doesn't using the raw ID work against modular implementation?

Comment: I think it would make the most sense to create the role in applicant.install file instead of relying on the CMS to tell you if the roll you describe is the roll you want. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: yes. you should insert the applicant role in the modules .install file. which will make sure that it's present. and as I already mentioned - you dont need that id. you can always just do `$account->roles[] = 'mynewrole';`

Answer (score 1):

Don't re-invent the wheel!  https://drupal.org/project/registration_role

Also I think you want to look at user_presave,  rather than user_insert.  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/7

Comment: hook_user_presave is also called on account edit.

Comment: but what if 4 lines of code all I want?

Comment: if you strip out the comments and unnecessary variables - my answer has 3 lines only ;)